# Gradient of Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I have these expressions, which are the gradient of a number of constraints on an optimization problem

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial z_r}=B(I\otimes z_r + z_r\otimes I - iI\otimes z_i + iz_i\otimes I) \\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial z_i}=B(iI\otimes z_r - iz_r\otimes I + I\otimes z_i + z_i\otimes I).$$

where

$$
q=z_r+iz_i.
$$

Furthermore, $c\in\mathbb{R}^{100}$, $(q, z_r, z_i)\in\ \mathbb{C}^{9}$, $B\in\mathbb{C}^{100\times 81}$ and $I\in\mathbb{R}^{9\times 9}$ is the identity matrix. Consequently, ($\frac{\partial c}{\partial z_r},\frac{\partial c}{\partial z_i})\in\mathbb{R}^{9\times100}$. I want to calculate the Hessian and therefore i require the gradient of the gradient (and thus $\frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial z_r^2}$ and the others).

This is what i have tried:

$$
d(X\otimes Y) = dX\otimes Y +X\otimes dY
$$
and so

$$
f=B(I\otimes z_r) \\
df = B(I\otimes dz_r).
$$

But i am not sure how to go to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_r}$ from here, since $dz_r$ is still part of the kronecker product.

Comment: Note that $f$ is a matrix and the Hessian will be a 3rd order tensor. So the best option available in standard matrix notation is to vectorize the equations, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
I &= \sum_{k=1}^9 e_ke_k^T \qquad
{\rm vec}(df) &= \sum_{k=1}^9 \Big(e_k\otimes B(e_k\otimes I)\Big)dz_r \\
}$$
where $\{e_k\}$ are the standard basis vectors.